# Accordion List Text-Align not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have code below for an accordion list I am creating. For some reason, when I add a text-align in my css properties to the 4 Items under the heading one it doesn't change. I want to have the four month activities in the center, but the text-align doesn't work. I have no idea what I did wrong. Can anyone see that problem? Cheers.

```js
( function( window ) {
'use strict';
function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}
var classie = {
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  define( classie );
} else {
  window.classie = classie;
}
})( window );
var $ = function(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');
accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if(classes) {
      for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if(classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
          var title = e.target;
          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
          classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');
          if(classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
            if(classie.has(content, 'animateOut')){
              classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'animateIn');
          }else{
             classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
             classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
          }
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
          classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');      
        }
      }
    }  
  }
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }
.accordion dl{
}

.bottombar{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:1em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}

.accordion dt > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #005bab;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion dd {
  background-color: #f4f8fc;
  color:#30353d;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.accordion dd > p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e1ecf7;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
  font-size:14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.accordionTitle:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #005bab;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover {
  background-color: #e8f0f7;
}

.accordionTitleActive {
  background-color:#e8f0f7;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}
@media all {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 100em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    transition: max-height 1.5s;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 50em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}

.accordionItemCollapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}


.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 2*/

.read-more-state2 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target2 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state2:checked ~ .read-more-wrap2 .read-more-target2 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state2 ~ .read-more-trigger2:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state2:checked ~ .read-more-trigger2:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 3*/

.read-more-state3 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target3 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state3:checked ~ .read-more-wrap3 .read-more-target3 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state3 ~ .read-more-trigger3:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state3:checked ~ .read-more-trigger3:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 4*/

.read-more-state4 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target4 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state4:checked ~ .read-more-wrap4 .read-more-target4 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state4 ~ .read-more-trigger4:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state4:checked ~ .read-more-trigger4:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger4 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*Read More Box 1 -two*/

.read-more-state-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap-two .read-more-target-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state-two ~ .read-more-trigger-two:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger-two:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
    color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 2 -two*/

.read-more-state2-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target2-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state2-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap2-two .read-more-target2-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state2-two ~ .read-more-trigger2-two:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state2-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger2-two:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
    color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger2-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 3 -two*/

.read-more-state3-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target3-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state3-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap3-two .read-more-target3-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state3-two ~ .read-more-trigger3-two:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state3-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger3-two:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
    color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger3-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 4 -two*/

.read-more-state4-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target4-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state4-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap4-two .read-more-target4-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state4-two ~ .read-more-trigger4-two:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state4-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger4-two:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
    color:#555555;
           text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger4-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="accordion"> 
      <dl> 
         <dt>
            <a class="accordionTitle" href="#"> 
               <span style="color: #005bab;">Heading One</span></a></dt> 
         <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed"> 

              <div> 
         <br/>
         <input class="read-more-state" id="post-1" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger" for="post-1"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap"> 
            <div class="read-more-target"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">Feb 28-Mar 10, 2017.</span><br/>feb</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state2" id="post-2" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger2" for="post-2"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap2"> 
            <div class="read-more-target2"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">W/C March 13</span><br/>march</p>
               <br/>  
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state3" id="post-3" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger3" for="post-3"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap3"> 
            <div class="read-more-target3"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">Apr 10, 2017</span><br/>April</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state4" id="post-4" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger4" for="post-4"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap4"> 
            <div class="read-more-target4"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">May 3-4, 2017</span><br/>May</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div>
         </dd>
         <div class="bottombar"> &#160;</div> 
      </dl> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put text-align center on class "dd".

```
.accordion dd {
  background-color: #f4f8fc;
  color:#30353d;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center/**Added this**/
}
```

```js
( function( window ) {
'use strict';
function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}
var classie = {
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  define( classie );
} else {
  window.classie = classie;
}
})( window );
var $ = function(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');
accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if(classes) {
      for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if(classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
          var title = e.target;
          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
          classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');
          if(classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
            if(classie.has(content, 'animateOut')){
              classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'animateIn');
          }else{
             classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
             classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
          }
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
          classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');      
        }
      }
    }  
  }
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }
.accordion dl{
}

.bottombar{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:1em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}

.accordion dt > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #005bab;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion dd {
  background-color: #f4f8fc;
  color:#30353d;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.accordion dd > p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e1ecf7;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
  font-size:14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.accordionTitle:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #005bab;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover {
  background-color: #e8f0f7;
}

.accordionTitleActive {
  background-color:#e8f0f7;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}
@media all {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 100em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    transition: max-height 1.5s;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 50em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}

.accordionItemCollapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}


.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 2*/

.read-more-state2 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target2 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state2:checked ~ .read-more-wrap2 .read-more-target2 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state2 ~ .read-more-trigger2:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state2:checked ~ .read-more-trigger2:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 3*/

.read-more-state3 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target3 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state3:checked ~ .read-more-wrap3 .read-more-target3 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state3 ~ .read-more-trigger3:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state3:checked ~ .read-more-trigger3:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 4*/

.read-more-state4 {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target4 {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state4:checked ~ .read-more-wrap4 .read-more-target4 {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state4 ~ .read-more-trigger4:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state4:checked ~ .read-more-trigger4:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger4 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*Read More Box 1 -two*/

.read-more-state-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap-two .read-more-target-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state-two ~ .read-more-trigger-two:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger-two:before {
  content: 'February Activities';
    color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 2 -two*/

.read-more-state2-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target2-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state2-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap2-two .read-more-target2-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state2-two ~ .read-more-trigger2-two:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state2-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger2-two:before {
  content: 'March Activities';
    color:#555555;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger2-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 3 -two*/

.read-more-state3-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target3-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state3-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap3-two .read-more-target3-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state3-two ~ .read-more-trigger3-two:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state3-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger3-two:before {
  content: 'April Activities';
    color:#555555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger3-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Read More Box 4 -two*/

.read-more-state4-two {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target4-two {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state4-two:checked ~ .read-more-wrap4-two .read-more-target4-two {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state4-two ~ .read-more-trigger4-two:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}

.read-more-state4-two:checked ~ .read-more-trigger4-two:before {
  content: 'May Activities';
    color:#555555;
           text-decoration: underline;
}

.read-more-trigger4-two {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="accordion"> 
      <dl> 
         <dt>
            <a class="accordionTitle" href="#"> 
               <span style="color: #005bab;">Heading One</span></a></dt> 
         <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed"> 

              <div> 
         <br/>
         <input class="read-more-state" id="post-1" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger" for="post-1"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap"> 
            <div class="read-more-target"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">Feb 28-Mar 10, 2017.</span><br/>feb</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state2" id="post-2" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger2" for="post-2"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap2"> 
            <div class="read-more-target2"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">W/C March 13</span><br/>march</p>
               <br/>  
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state3" id="post-3" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger3" for="post-3"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap3"> 
            <div class="read-more-target3"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">Apr 10, 2017</span><br/>April</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <div> 
         <input class="read-more-state4" id="post-4" type="checkbox"/> 
         <label class="read-more-trigger4" for="post-4"></label> 
         <div class="read-more-wrap4"> 
            <div class="read-more-target4"> 
               <br/> 
               <p class="p">
                  <span class="bold">May 3-4, 2017</span><br/>May</p>
               <br/> 
            </div> 
         </div> 
      </div>
         </dd>
         <div class="bottombar"> &#160;</div> 
      </dl> 
   </div> 
</div>
```